Idle mixture, or idle throttle stop?
This particular situation is related to a motorcycle (1986 rebel 450) but I see myself encountering this problem occasionally and I'd like to understand at a conceptual level how to work through it.
How do I know which of my two are out of adjustment - idle mixture or idle throttle position?
The bike idles high when warm. Again - that's not necessarily relevant as this is a question every time I build/adjust a carb. I could argue it's a touch lean, because the revs hang a little bit when I rev it. However, I could also argue that the throttle is cracked too far open when it's "closed". Short of putting a sensor in the exhaust to measure what's happening, is there any way to figure out which to adjust first?

They might both need adjusting, and the throttle stop is trivial compared with mixture adjustment. Don't you adjust them alternately?

Yes, but I can get the throttle stop low enough that it idles nicely, but then it dies when richening the mixture. How do I know that the mixture is too rich, and not that the throttle stop is in the wrong spot?
I guess if the engine sounds and idles happy then all is well, I'm possibly overthinking it

Did you try searching then joining Honda motorcycle forums for members familiar with your questions? There are probably youtube videos too.

If given that task I would approach it in two stages.

Find the most efficient settings, by alternately adjusting the mixture to maximise the engine revs and reducing the idle throttle. Without revving it (except perhaps to settle the throttle stop).

If you feel that it's not responsive enough to produce power, adjust the mixture towards lean or rich as you think is right, in small steps, and increase the throttle stop to regain good idling revs. If further adjustment doesn't make it any more repsonsive, back off the mixture setting.


You could go through this a few times, until you know when to stop adjusting the mixture in step 2.

This is a fantastic answer. I had tried this and struggled quite a lot. Turns out the throttle cables were sticking (needed lubing) and that made it significantly easier to tune it
